Multiple processes in docker container cannot recieve term signal
My k8s deployment file is
      - name: ztest
        image: xxx/test
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
        - ./run.sh
        - hello

run.sh is like
for d in plugins_"$repo_name"/*/;
do
  ./ztest --config-location "$dir"/ --config-name $(basename "$filename")&
done;
wait

go codes
type Pipeline struct {
}

func (p *Pipeline) ProcessBlock() {
  // call other p *Pipeline functions
}

func (p *Pipeline) Run() {
    // Setting up a channel to listen to signals
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Channel to control the termination of the main loop
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        p.Deps.Logger.Info("Waiting for signals....")
        sig := <-sigChan
        p.Deps.Logger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Received signal: %v, waiting for function f to finish", sig))
        done <- true
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        default:
            p.ProcessBlock()
        }

    }
}

I did not see Received signal: %v, waiting for function f to finish when i killed the container...
any idea why? thanks

The main container process is your run.sh script, and Docker sends SIGTERM only to that process.  You might be able to trap the signal and then kill each of the subprocesses (I don't have a recipe off hand though).  Can you instead split this up so that you have a set of containers, each of which runs just one process, without a shell-script wrapper?

It looks like in your run.sh you are looping through $repo_name using $d as an identifier but you are not using the identifier anywhere in the later part of the code. In the 3rd line of the script you are using $dir is that a completely new variable?? Or $d needs to replace in place of $dir ?
